# Try-Catch, How to make the program catch an unrecognised value

Tags: c#, try-catch

How do I tell the program to catch an error where the user enters something that is not recognised? E.G. instead of USD or EURO, they enter 40 or sdfsdf or 4f43f. Thanks

```
Console.WriteLine("This is a Currency Converter --- Ver A1.00");


Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");

Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of money:");

value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("Great, Now we must select which currency you want to convert to:");

Console.WriteLine("Type: USD or EURO");

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");

Rate = Console.ReadLine();


try

{


}


catch

{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
}
```

Comment: Ummm... put an if statement to see if they entered one of those? Do you know how to write an if statement?

Comment: Use an `if` statement to check what it's equal to?

Comment: Also, its weird that your "enter a number" is in the `catch` block. That would imply that you only want them to do that if the original code caused an *error*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the user input in your `try` statement not in the `catch` statement.

Here's something for you to start. After you read the input from user to enter `USD` or `EURO` check and see what user entered. If the input is either `USD` or `EURO` do the conversation, otherwise force the user to re enter the value.

```
try
{
   Console.WriteLine("This is a Currency Converter --- Ver A1.00");
   Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
   Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
   Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of money:");

   double value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
   Console.WriteLine("");
   Console.WriteLine("Great, Now we must select which currency you want to convert to:");

   Console.WriteLine("Type: USD or EURO");
   Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");

   var Rate = Console.ReadLine();

   bool result = false;

   while (result == false)
   {

      if (Rate == "USD" || Rate == "EURO")
      {
        //do the converion
        result = true;
      }

      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Incorrect value. Enter USD or EURO");
         Rate = Console.ReadLine();

         if (Rate == "USD" || Rate == "EURO")
         {
           //do the converion
           result = true;
         }
         else
         {
            result = false;
         }

       }
     }
   }
```

NOTE* you do need to check the `AMOUNT` also. What if the user enters `abdfsdf` instead of a number? Then your code will go to a `catch` statement.

This is something for you to start with.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you get USD and Euro with Corresponding numbers (like 1 for USD and 2 for EURO)
and then  use some code like this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool showErrorMessage = false;
        static void calc(int number)
        {
            if (number==1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("USD");
            }
            else if (number == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EURO");
            }
            else
            {
                getNumber();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void getNumber()
        {
            if (showErrorMessage)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Entered Invalid Number ,Only 1 and 2 Valid, Please Try Again :");
            }
            int number = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToString(),out number))
            {
                calc(number);
            }
            else
            {
                showErrorMessage = true;
                getNumber();

            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getNumber();
        }
    }
}
```